# GIt rebase not working. Waiting for editor to close a file

Tags: git, git-rebase

I installed chocolatey and was looking forward to using it as a rebase tool because the rebase tool I get with vs code was glitchy. It wasn't working properly. When I tried using `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, I get this error.

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:/path/to/interactive-rebase-tool.exe': C:/path/to/interactive-rebase-tool.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:/path/to/interactive-rebase-tool.exe''.
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is with your editor or its path.

Check the configure path of your editor in Git. Is it really exist.

for example if you are using notepad++ here is the command

```
git config core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Comment: Im using vs code, can you please provide a command for that ???

Comment: sequence.editor='C:/path/to/interactive-rebase-tool.exe'
core.editor=emacs  any idea what a sequence.editor is and how to change it